# Strange big number of variables in multinom() function in R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

When I run the `multinom()` function in R, the number of variables in the result is very big while I only have a few predictor variables in the formula. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how can I resolve it? (`mv_daily` only takes 0 and 1, `icu_loc` takes 0,1,2 in the data.)

I tried 3 predictor variables and the number of variables in the result increased to 1230! The program takes each distinct value of a predictor variable as a different variable in the results and gives it a different coefficient.

```
newdata2 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/input_multinom_reg_March9_csv.csv")
library(nnet)
test <- multinom(state_tomorrow ~ mv_daily + icu_loc, newdata2,maxit=400,MaxNWts=2000)
```

Results:

```
 Call:
 multinom(formula = state_tomorrow ~ mv_day2 + icu_loc, data = newdata2, 
 maxit = 400, MaxNWts = 2000)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    mv_daily    icu_loc
F     3.6303751 -1.1223394 -0.3681095
H     1.2178084 -1.3153864  0.3721295
IND   0.4628305 -2.1366738 -1.2530020
PR    2.2952981 -1.3085620 -0.4032178
RRT   0.1000952 -0.6432881  0.7659957

# weights:  24 (15 variable)
initial  value 18682.675986 
iter  10 value 12929.391832
iter  20 value 12341.441938
final  value 12284.346914
```

Data look like this:

```
id  state_tomorrow  day  mv_daily  icu_loc
1     F              1      0         1
1     RRT            2      1         1
2     PR             4      1         0
2     PR             5      1         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When estimating multinomial models, one should expect a separate parameter estimate for each factor level.

Comment: Hi @IShouldBuyABoat. Yes I know we should expect a separate parameter estimate for each factor level. The problem is when I use nlevels(icu_loc) and nlevels(mv_daily) both of them have 3 or less levels and I have no idea where does 15 levels in the regression comes.

Comment: I only see a report that has 5 coefficients. Where are you seeing "15 levels"?

Comment: Now I get this thank you! Also how about the variables that are not factorized. I don't want to have separate parameter for each different value of those parameters. What should I do?

Comment: I think you are not going to succeed with `multinom` since that assumes all variables are factors, I think you need to use a log-linear modeling framework, perhaps `glm( formula, data, "poisson")`